# Failed to execute goal org.apache.felix:maven-scr-plugin:1.17.0:scr

Tags: maven, aem

Started to work with AEM project. Now I am trying to launch project locally and got next error during building (stacktrace cut):

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.felix:maven-scr-plugin:1.17.0:scr (generate-scr-scrdescriptor) on project canadian-tire-site-core: Execution generate-scr-scrdescriptor of goal org.apache.felix:maven-scr-plugin:1.17.0:scr failed: org.apache.felix.scrplugin.annotations.AnnotationProcessor is not an ImageIO SPI class -> [Help 1]
            org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.felix:maven-scr-plugin:1.17.0:scr (generate-scr-scrdescriptor) on project canadian-tire-site-core: Execution generate-scr-scrdescriptor of goal org.apache.felix:maven-scr-plugin:1.17.0:scr failed: org.apache.felix.scrplugin.annotations.AnnotationProcessor is not an ImageIO SPI class
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213) .....
      Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution generate-scr-scrdescriptor of goal org.apache.felix:maven-scr-plugin:1.17.0:scr failed: org.apache.felix.scrplugin.annotations.AnnotationProcessor is not an ImageIO SPI class
            at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:145) ....
      Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.apache.felix.scrplugin.annotations.AnnotationProcessor is not an ImageIO SPI class
            at javax.imageio.spi.ServiceRegistry.checkClassAllowed (ServiceRegistry.java:745) ....
```

Piece of config file:

```
            <!-- Apache Felix SCR Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scr-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.17.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-scr-scrdescriptor</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>scr</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <properties>
                                <service.vendor>CTC</service.vendor>
                            </properties>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
                        <version>1.5.11</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

I have also checked Java and mvn versions and looks like everything fine here:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4

mvn -v
 Apache Maven 3.5.2 
 Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.5.2-bin
 Java version: 9.0.4, vendor: Oracle Corporation
 Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4
```

Would be great if someone can advice in which direction I should look.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

AEM 6.3 does [not support](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/deploying/using/technical-requirements.html#JavaVirtualMachines) `JDK 9`.

Take a look at this [jira bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FELIX-5118?attachmentOrder=asc) for a workaround for your issue if you want to continue experimenting with JAVA 1.9 and AEM.

Comment: yes, after I downloaded  JDK 8 and updated JAVA_HOME , everything started to work