# getting error while executing mvn clean install command

Tags: java, maven, aem

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.felix:maven-scr-plugin:1.7.4:scr (generate-scr-descriptor) on project slingjcr-bundle: Execution generate-scr-descriptor of goal org.apache.felix:maven-scr-plugin:1.7.4:scr failed: org.apache.felix.scrplugin.tags.annotation.AnnotationTagProvider is not an ImageIO SPI class -> [Help 1]`enter code here`
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :slingjcr-bundle
```

hello there i'm working on AEM project so while executing mvn clean install getting the error mentioned above.i am using java 11 and maven 3.6.2 ,running AEM 6.5

Comment: have you tried running the command again with the -e switch?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to execute goal org.apache.felix:maven-scr-plugin:1.17.0:scr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48953513/failed-to-execute-goal-org-apache-felixmaven-scr-plugin1-17-0scr)

Comment: after running -e switch it gives following error:Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution generate-scr-descriptor of goal org.apache.felix:maven-scr-plugin:1.7.4:scr failed: org.apache.felix.scrplugin.tags.annotation.AnnotationTagProvider is not an ImageIO SPI class
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.apache.felix.scrplugin.tags.annotation.AnnotationTagProvider is not an ImageIO SPI class

Comment: my AEM version is 6.5 and running java 11 (jdk 11.0.4)which is supported by 6.5

Comment: Are you migrating from an older AEM 6.x to AEM 6.5?

Answer (score 1):

First, You are on AEM 6.5, if this is a new project, please use OSGI R6 or R7 instead of Felix SCR annotations. See: [[1]](http://www.nateyolles.com/blog/2017/05/osgi-declarative-services-annotations-in-aem) and [[2]](http://blogs.adobe.com/experiencedelivers/experience-management/osgi/using-osgi-r7-annotations-aem/)

If this is an existing project and you really just want SCR annotations to work, then you need to use the latest version of the maven-scr-plugin.

This specific issue was fixed in version `1.22.0` fo `the maven-scr-plugin` according to: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FELIX-5118?attachmentOrder=asc

you are using version `1.7.4` of the plugin. The latest as of this answer is `1.26.2`

see: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.felix/maven-scr-plugin

Answer (score 0):

If you use a Java JDK 1.8 this issue is not arising. If you use later version, probably you get similar errors because package and classes are changed between versions.